# CSS :hover only works on first instance of class

Tags: css

```
.Row:hover .Contents  { background-color:Blue; }

<div class="Row">
   <span class="Contents">Row Contents</span>
</div>
<div class="Row">
    <span class="Contents">Row Contents</span>
</div>
```

In the above sample, only the first Row Contents responds to hover. See http://jsfiddle.net/3JRTQ/.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, particularly since .Row .Contents {} works for all instances just fine.

I don't want to highlight the entire row - just the span with text, but I want the whole row to respond to hover.

Is this possible with CSS only?

Comment: That fiddle works as expected, what are your expectations?

Comment: Actually, it's not working as expected in Chrome (at least not 25.0.1364.58 beta) In Firefox and Safari, the background color of each row changes on hover. In Chrome only the first. If you force the hover state in the inspector on another row, the hover state of that row will then work.

Comment: Does work in Chrome if you put the hover on .Contents instead of .Row http://jsfiddle.net/Me6QZ/1/

Comment: The fiddle in the question works fine in Chrome for me. Win7/64, version 24.

Comment: Works fine for me in 24 and 26.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hit a [bug in Chrome 25 (and 26, too)](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=171867). Remember, always try another browser.

Answer (score 0):

Fix for this example.  Make the Span the hover

```
.Row .Contents:hover  { background-color:Blue; }
```

OR make the Div the element that is going to be changing:

```
.Row:hover { background-color:Blue; }
```

Hope this helps